# Executing PHP: detecting when a link has been clicked

Tags: php, html, function, queue, hyperlink

I've got a bit of a dilemma with some PHP code. The site I'm working on has a "Back to Previous Page" option and I'd like it to behave much like a browser's back button. As it stands right now, I'm using a $_SESSION variable to track what the current and previous pages are. I've also "refresh-proofed" the variables so that I don't end up with both the previous and current pages being the same.

So here's the issue:
With the current implementation, if I go to one page, say "register.php" and then go to "forgot.php", the previous page will be "register.php" which is fine. However, if I click "Back to Previous Page" I'll end up back at "register.php" with the previous page being "forgot.php" which now leaves me with a 2-page loop with going back.

I tried implementing SplQueue to help me keep track of variables and I tried using the dequeue() function in my links to get the last page to show up as the link. The problem comes in when the dequeue is actually called and causes the element to disappear so that if I refresh, the element is no longer in the queue and the link changes. I fixed this by "refresh-proofing" the function that calls the dequeue for me and it works as I would like it to. The problem is now forward-linking. If I direct myself to another page, I don't want the old links to dequeue information.

Ex:
I'm on register.php and my previous page is "forgot.php". The "Back to Previous Page" link accurately shows that "forgot.php" is the page it will direct to, but now it's no longer in the queue, so if I go to another page, say "profile.php" and then use the back button to go back to "register.php", it will no longer show "forgot.php" as the page that you will go to if you hit "Back to Previous Page" again.

So, I guess my question is really how I can make a link call a PHP function without actually calling that function UNTIL the link has been clicked. I've tried having the link point to a JavaScript function, but the JS functions tend to tell me that my queue is empty, which is completely wrong.

As a side note, the pages are a mix of HTML and PHP. The HTML is supplied to me and I've been adding the PHP in to add functionality to fields and to get data from a database. I have no problem using PHP to echo the HTML links if I have to, and if it can be done in HTML with a small `<?php someCode(); ?>`, that's fine too.

I thank you for your time to try and help me out.

**EDIT:**

So to try and clarify a bit, I have a structure that is currently tracking pages that the user has already been to as they visit them. It creates a mini history of the pages. My issue is that I have code like this:

```
<a href="somelink">Back To Previous Page</a>
```

And I don't know what "somelink" is since it will change depending on your history. I know I can do something like:

```
<a href="<?php someFunction() ?>">Back To Previous Page</a>
```

If I do anything like the above, the function is executed as the page is being displayed, so it makes it difficult to use an `array_pop()` or a `dequeue()` but again, the PHP will be executed as soon as the page is displayed. What I'm looking for is a way to display the link and then remove it from the history if and only if the "Back to Previous Page" link is clicked. As of right now, I'm storing an array in `$_SESSION` as was suggested below and since it's an array, I can show the last element in the array as the link, so the only real problem is to find a way to remove elements from the array when the link is clicked.

**EDIT 2:**

I've been scouring the internet and decided upon using JavaScript with AJAX to call a PHP file. This allows me to us an onClick on the links I have so that I can control when I `array_pop` from my `$_SESSION['links']` variable.

I don't think my AJAX is actually doing anything sadly, so the code I'm using is below.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">
function dequeue()
{
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "common.php",
            data: {action: "rem"},
            success: function(output) {
                  alert(output);
              }
        });
}
</script>
```

and the PHP is

```
switch($_POST['action'])
{
case "rem":
    array_pop($_SESSION['links']);
    break;
default:
    if(isset($_SESSION['current']) && $_SESSION['current'] != $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
    {
        array_push($_SESSION['links'], $_SESSION['current']);
    }

    $_SESSION['current'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    break;
}
```

As far as I can tell, this will allow me to add a link to the history in the session variable unless I'm clicking on the "Back to Previous Page" link since that link will have the "rem" code. I'm also a bit suspicious of the `$_SESSION['current'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` and where it should be placed.

Comment: I don't quite get the problem, but the title is interesting. PHP only executes when a link is clicked (or you have some JS code initiating a request, which you also you control over).

Comment: @NullUserException Yeah, PHP is executed when a link is clicked, but I needed more of a way to execute specific function AND redirect to another page. So once a link is clicked, go to that page and execute a specific function that would be used with every link. However, the solutions below get rid of the need for a function to be executed

Comment: I lied. A function still appears to be needed unless there is some other way to detect if a link had been clicked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store array in a session and treat the array like a stack (use `array_push` and `array_pop` accordingly). When the user hits something but the back button, push the current page to the stack. otherwise, pop it.

Comment: Using stacks to store browsing data is so 1990s. All current browsers can go forwards and backwards, so a stack doesn't quite cut it.

Comment: @NullUserException I don't really need to worry about going forward because the "Back to Previous Page" is a link on the current page and should behave like a browser's "back" button, or at least that's how I'd like it to work

Comment: @LeleDumbo I'll try that since it seems the same as the answer Ben posted below. Good to know that I can push/pop as needed and treat it like a queue or stack

Comment: @LeleDumbo I'm still a bit at a loss as to how to know when the back button has been pushed, which is what the original issue was. I have no problem saving the history and I was doing that with an SplQueue before, but I have no way of pinpointing when the user clicks the "Back to Previous Page" link

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this if I had to:

```
$_SESSION["history"] = array();
```

And within the header of every "rememberable" page:

```
if(in_array($this_page, $_SESSION["history"])) {
    unset($_SESSION["history"][array_search($this_page, $_SESSION["history"])]);
}
array_push($_SESSION["history"], $this_page);
```

What this does is: "If the page exists in the history, remove it from wherever it is and put it as the last page of the history. If not, just put it as the last page of the history". That way you won't have any loops.

Comment: I'm fine with some of the looping, just not with the history being limited to just two pages always bouncing back to each other. I'd essentially create what is the equivalent of a browser's back button, so if you went register->forgot->register->index, I'd like to be able to follow that route. Moving pages that already exist would leave weird gaps. Using the second group of code with my example would allow me to get back to "forgot" but not to the "register" before it. I appreciate the input and I'll definitely toy around with it. Hopefully I can get it to work

Comment: I see how this would work, but I'm more looking for a way to just identify when a user has clicked on the "Back to Previous Page" link so that I know when not to add to the history.